# Unicode with json.parse() in AS3?

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash, unicode, utf-8

I am reading a JSON file into an Actionscript 3 project, The file is valid according to JSON Validator but Flash 11 gives me Error #1132: Invalid JSON parse input.

Removing the unicode in this clears the error:

```
{
    "vars": {
        "0": {
            "id": "128",
            "varName": "dp",
            "varValue": "FLASHFAN",
            "category": "1"
        },
        "1": {
            "id": "129",
            "varName": "np",
            "varValue": "ERIK EKL\u00d6F",
            "category": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

The \u00d6 unicode seems to create a problem. Why is this?

Comment: Works for me with the native `JSON` class in flash player 11+

Comment: Try it in IE8. I'm having this error with a flash app that reads in JSON from the flash vars, it ONLY throws the error in IE8. IE11, Chrome, Firefox, all fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your code and everything works fine. I used flex 4.6 compiler and 11 FP.

```
var json:* = {
    "vars": {
        "0": {
            "id": "128",
            "varName": "dp",
            "varValue": "FLASHFAN",
            "category": "1"
        },
        "1": {
            "id": "129",
            "varName": "np",
            "varValue": "ERIK EKL\u00d6F",
            "category": "1"
        }
    }
}

var str:String = JSON.stringify(json);
var newObj:* = JSON.parse(str);
trace(newObj);
```

Comment: Try it in IE8.  I'm having this error with a flash app that reads in JSON from the flash vars, it ONLY throws the error in IE8.  IE11, Chrome, Firefox, all fine.